# jQuery division of two time to get the ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery

So they have this formula to get their ratio. It is 

`total working hours = time-start - time-end`
`ratio = total working hours / duration`
I can get the `total working hours` using this code,

```js
var timestart = '11:32:59 AM';
var timeend = '5:24:04 PM';
var duration = '00:44:08';

var totalworkinghours = timemod3(timestart, timeend);
console.log(totalworkinghours);

function timemod3(start, end) { //(H:MM:SS AM/PM) // GET THE DIFFERENCE OF TWO TIME
  //get the 24 hour format of start time
  Number.prototype.padDigit = function() {
    return (this < 10) ? '0' + this : this;
  }
  var ssplit = start.split(':');
  //var hour = ssplit[0];
  //var minutes = ssplit[1];
  var ss2 = ssplit[2].split(' ');
  var ampm1 = ss2[1]; //start

  var ssplit2 = end.split(':');
  //var hour2 = ssplit2[0];
  //var minutes2 = ssplit[1];
  var ss3 = ssplit2[2].split(' ');
  var ampm2 = ss3[1]; //end

  var st = convertTo24hr(start);
  var et = convertTo24hr(end);
  /************************************/
  var st1;
  var en;
  if (ampm1 == 'AM' && ampm2 == "PM") {
    //if sched is morning
    st1 = et;
    en = st;
  } else if (ampm1 == 'PM' && ampm2 == "AM") {
    //if sched is evening
    st1 = st;
    en = et;
  }
  var s = st1.split(':');
  var e = en.split(':');
  var se = Number(s[2]) - Number(e[2]);
  var sems = Math.floor(parseInt(se / 60));
  var mi = Number(s[1]) - Number(e[1]) - sems;
  var mihr = Math.floor(parseInt(mi / 60));
  var hr = Number(s[0]) - Number(e[0]) - mihr;

  if (se < 0) {
    mi = mi - 1;
    se = se + 60;
  }
  if (mi < 0) {
    hr = hr - 1;
    mi = mi + 60;
  }
  if (hr < 0) {
    //se = 0;
    //mi = 0;
    hr = 0;
  }
  var result = hr.padDigit() + ':' + mi.padDigit() + ':' + se.padDigit();
  if (result == 'NaN:NaN:' + se) {
    result = '00:00:00';
  }
  return result;
}

function convertTo24hr(time) {
  var t = time.split(':');
  var hours = Number(t[0]);
  var minutes = Number(t[1]);
  var t2 = t[2].split(' ');
  var sec = t2[0];
  var AMPM = t2[1];
  if ((AMPM == "pm" || AMPM == "PM") && hours < 12) {
    hours = hours + 12;
  }
  if ((AMPM == "am" || AMPM == "AM") && hours == 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
  }
  var sHours = hours.toString();
  var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
  if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
  if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;
  return (sHours + ':' + sMinutes + ':' + sec);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I don't know how to get the ratio. Help me get the ratio. And by the way, the result of it in excel is `7.95506` roundup to make it `8` so the ratio is `8`.

Comment: What is the difference between duration and totalworkinghours? Are you comparing the amount of time an employee worked in a day to his entire work history?

Comment: the duration is the duration of the file they are working.

Comment: the total working hours is the time it takes for them to finish the file.

Comment: What exactly do you have problems with the ratio calculation? You could normalize both values to seconds units then divide.

Comment: yeah your right! I can convert them to seconds and then get the ratio. Thank you for the idea. I will be back later to post my answer to this question.  But there is 1 problem now. How can I roundup the result to make it a whole number? I mean I don't know what is the code for roundup in jquery.

Comment: See JavaScript's [Math functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) `.round()`, `.floor()` and `.ceil()`

Comment: Be careful when rounding that you may lose accuracy.. for instance 3 : 7.6 is not the same as 3 : 8. So you would have to recalculate the proportionate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the total working hours and duration are given in xx:xx:xx time format, convert the times into seconds before dividing to get the ratio.

```
var myTotalHours = '05:51:05';
var myDuration =  '00:44:08';

function determineRatio(totalHours, duration) {

    var totalHoursArray = totalHours.split(':');
    var durationArray = duration.split(':');

    var numerator = parseInt(totalHoursArray[0])*3600 
        + parseInt(totalHoursArray[1])*60 
        + parseInt(totalHoursArray[2]);
    var denominator = parseInt(durationArray[0])*3600 
        + parseInt(durationArray[1])*60 
        + parseInt(durationArray[2]);

    return Math.round(numerator/denominator);

}

alert(determineRatio(myTotalHours,myDuration));
```